# Convexity of Binomial Term

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-coefficients, convex-analysis

I am reading a book on the probabilistic method, and the following claim was made:

$\dbinom{y}{n}$ is convex.

Why is this the case?

Comment: I think it's even convex if you take the log of it

Comment: can you prove it for me?

Comment: @Henry Concavity with respect to n is out of the question, by inspection for y=6 or by comparison with a normal density when y is large.

Comment: @Did: Fair enough - I will delete that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Compare $\dfrac{\dbinom{y+1}{n} }{\dbinom{y}{n}}$ with $\dfrac{\dbinom{y}{n} }{\dbinom{y-1}{n}}$ for $y \gt n$

Comment: I admit that I don't see how this leads to a proof that the sequence is convex in y. But I think that considering the differences instead of the ratios, will work.